# Показывать и скрывать контент на плюс , минус

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nilsons20000/m5p86o2q/1/)
С одним плюсом,когда нажимаешь ,  прекрасно работает , но когда там два и больше , то открывает все и закрывает все. Помогите , пожалуйста, вроде написано `this` но почему то работает всё равно на все. Так как почему то тут плюсик не отображается , написал его вручную `"+"`  Должен открывать нажатый и закрывать его же

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $content.slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle{
  display:inline-block;
 height:48px;
 width:100%;  
 }


 .toggle::after{
   float: right;
  display:inline-block;
 height:48px;
 width:48px;  
 content:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
 }
 .toggle.expanded::after{
   content:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
 }



.toggle{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">+</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<br >

<div class="toggle">+</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: это вообще без js сделать можно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $(".content");
  $content.hide();
  $(".toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).on('click',function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
      $(this).next($content).fadeToggle(0);
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle{
  display:block;
  height:48px;
  width:48px;  
  background:url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pixelmixer/basic/48/plus-icon.png");
}
.toggle.expanded{
  background:url("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/onebit/PNG/onebit_32.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">+</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>


<div class="toggle">+</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Это и без each будет работать) `$('.toggle').on('click'...` и дальше всё то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь )

Comment: это даже без js будет работать

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expanded').next('.content').toggle();
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle::after {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  content: '+';
}

.toggle.expanded::after {
  content: '-';
}

.toggle {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<br>

<div class="toggle"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик

Answer (score 2):

Так `$content` содержи в себе все ноды класса *'content'* .

Нужно делать например так (если контент расположен сразу после кнопки):

```
$(this).next(".content").slideToggle();
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uypqscjg/2/)

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик